# Adding empty or null on arraylist in java

Tags: java

I am trying to search account numbers on an excel file, which in return, i will get a 'total amount due' if the  account number exists in the sheet. I can scan using this code, however, I get error if the account number does not exists in the sheet.

```
for(int i = 0; i < accno.size(); i++){
    for(int j = rowAccNo1+1; j < row.getRowNum(); j++){
           srcaccno = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(0));
           totalamt = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(10));

          if(accno.get(i).contains(srcaccno)){
                  totalamountdue.add(i, totalamt);
          }
      }
  }
```

Edit:
Hi, I am using Apache POI.

I declared accno as below:

```
static ArrayList<String> accno = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I am getting this error. perhaps Java can't find the account number that's why he throws this. But I do not know if I can add an empty or null on my arraylist.

> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source) at
>   com.joven.DataExtractionTool.App.compareMastertoSourceABC(App.java:372)
>   at com.joven.DataExtractionTool.App.main(App.java:78) at
>   com.joven.DataExtractionTool.AppTest.testApp(AppTest.java:17) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154) at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127) at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106) at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124) at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109) at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118) at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208) at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203) at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:131)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Thank you for your response!

What I really like to do is that, if accno exists in the sheet, get totalamountdue. if it does not exists, put blank on totalamountdue so that it will display blank if i output the arraylist in console.

Comment: It would help if you also let us know which Excel Java library you are using (I'm guessing Apache).

Comment: How about using *conditional Operation* ?

Comment: What is the type of `accno`, can it contains `null` ? This doesn't seems right `if(accno.get(i).contains(srcaccno)){`

Comment: Apologies. see my edit. thank you!

Comment: The short version, you add into the list into a specific index, when you don't find the account, you have a gap, `List` don't like to add value into a index bigger than their current size. Now, did you need to have the List to match the account one ? I guess, so  you need to add a default value if the account is not foud (null, -1, ...)

Comment: but if the account is not found, it stops the loop. doing my best to get fix as well. thank you for quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem come from this

```
if(accno.get(i).contains(srcaccno)){
     totalamountdue.add(i, totalamt); // ########
}
```

Since you add the `total` to a specific index in the list (the one corresponding to the account list), you need to insert a "default" value if you don't find the account in the sheet. If you do not, you will have a different length between the account list and the total list. Meaning that you try to add a value to far (out of bounds exception).

Actually, there is a much easier way (don't know why I didn't think first)

Before you even start to search into the sheet, insert a null value

```
totalamountdue.add(null);
```

Then, in the search loop, if you find a value replace this `null` with the total found.

```
if(accno.get(i).contains(srcaccno)){
     totalamountdue.set(i, totalamt); // use SET to replace the value at a specific index.
}
```

The full loop

```
totalamoutdue.add(null); //will insert at the end, i.
for(int j = rowAccNo1+1; j < row.getRowNum(); j++){
      srcaccno = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(0));
      if(accno.get(i).contains(srcaccno)){
              totalamt = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(10)); //No need to get the value if it is not the account you want
              totalamountdue.set(i, totalamt);
              break; //Break the current for loop, IF there is no need to read further
      }
  }
```

Comment: you are correct, the problem is coming come that line. because if acc.get(i) is not on the excel file, it stops the loop. :( if I add else, like `else{totalamountdue.add(i, ""); ` i get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` error.

Comment: @ashlrem Don't insert in the else part, this will add for each row of the sheet. I have edited my answer a bit. PS : It doesn't stopped the loop, it crashed ;)

Comment: your tip about not having else is great man. followed your suggestion about .set and break; and it works great!

Comment: @ashlrem The break is usefull **if** there is no duplicated row for a same account. But if this is not the case, you should use a tmp variable to do the sum of all corresponding values then set the result.

Comment: oh you are right once again. i doubt there would be duplicated row. or i hope there would be no duplicated row. for now, my code works. and it is all thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume something is wrong with iterating over those lists, so I simplified code - hope it will work.

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> accountsDue = new HashMap<>();

for (int j = rowAccNo1 + 1; j < row.getRowNum(); j++) {
  String srcaccno = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(0));
  BigDecimal amountDue = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(j).getCell(10));
  if (accno.contains(srcaccno)) {
    putOrIncreaseDue(srcaccno, amountDue, accountsDue);
  }
}

private void putOrIncreaseDue(String srcaccno, BigDecimal amountDue, Map<String, BigDecimal> accountsDue) {
  if (accountsDue.containsKey(srcaccno)) {
    amountDue.add(accountsDue.get(srcaccno));
  }
  accountsDue.put(srcaccno, amountDue);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can i ask what do you mean by this? `amountDue = amountDue.add(accountsDue.get(srcaccno)); }`

Comment: can you kindly explain what the `putOrIncreaseDue` method does? thanks!

Comment: I created map - Account number as key, and AmountDue as value.

Comment: When I want to put parsed value to this map - first I need to check if it's already there. If so - get current AmountDue value add parsed value, and then put. Otherwise just put with parsed value.

Comment: This will duplicate the Account value in memory, once in the map, once in the list.

Comment: would like to try your idea, but i am having a red line here `amountDue = amountDue.add(accountsDue.get(srcaccno)); ` and eclipse wants me to change thr type of amountDue to boolean..

Comment: my bad - it should be
if (accountsDue.containsKey(srcaccno)) {
   amountDue.add(accountsDue.get(srcaccno));
}